# selenium webdriver (c#) - Best way to iterate through a select menu - Then verify an elements style updates?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to iterate through all available options inside a select menu, click on each option in turn, then verify that clicking on each option will update a particular element with a width and height value.

Here is the code for the select menu:

```
 <span id="SizeSelectContainer" class="dropdownButton" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 120px;">
            <select id="SizeSelect" title="Zoom" tabindex="23" data-l10n-id="zoom" style="min-width: 126px;">
                <option id="SizeAutoOption" title="" value="auto" selected="selected" data-l10n-id="pagesizeauto">Automatic Size</option>
                <option id="SizeActualOption" title="" value="page-size-actual" data-l10n-id="pagesizeactual">Actual Size</option>
                <option title="" value="0.1">10</option>
                <option title="" value="0.5">50</option>
                <option title="" value="1">100</option>                         
            </select>
        </span>
```

When I click on each option, the value within another element located elsewhere on the page will change (see below) - There is no "selected" attribute applied to any of the drop down options when selected (apart from the default option) so I can't assert the selections based on a "selected" attribute.

What I'm going to do (which I haven't coded in my sample yet) is that when a particular select option is selected, another page element (shown below) will update to hold new width and height values:

```
<div id="Container" class="page" style="width: 547px; height: 865px; data-loaded="true">
```

Here is what I have come up with so far - Note that I know I'm not asserting anything yet

```
        IWebElement AutoSize = UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.Id("SizeAutoOption"));
        IWebElement ActualSize = UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.Id("SizeActualOption"));

        IWebElement Ten = UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='SizeSelect']/option[3]"));
        IWebElement Fifty = UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='SizeSelect']/option[4]"));
        IWebElement Hundred = UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='SizeSelect']/option[5]"));  

        Object[] SelectElements = new Object[] { AutoSize, ActualSize, Ten, Fifty, Hundred };

        for (int i = 0; i < SelectElements.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                AutoSize.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                ActualSize.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                Ten.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                Fifty.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                Hundred.Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
         }
```

I'm really just looking for some confirmation on whether or not this will be the best way to approach this.  The reason I ask is that I have essentially simplified the code sample above and I actually have over 50 select options to verify - not to mention that I have many other select menus with as many options contained inside them to automate.

Comment: If you have a lot of options you may want to drive this with meta data.  I.e. have a database table that has the option, the selector, and the expected result so that you'll load up that metadata and then do a foreach in code.  That way when you get a new option, all you have to do is update your metadata rather than the code itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got several problems here.

The first is that a `for` loop is not what you want to do.

The second is that Selenium wraps all the "find me an option within a select" functionality for you in a `SelectElement` class so you don't have to do this in the first place:

The third is that your XPath constructs are heavily based on position. Position is bad because it's something that can change. If I add in an option at the very top of that list, your test will break and it should not. I've not broken application functionality, merely just changed the list order, and your test is going to fail.

The fourth problem is you are holding references to your element and you've said the page is going to change when you click the option. This, *may*, cause a `StaleReferenceException` dependant on what the click actually does. I say *may* because it *shouldn't* but if your application is coded to do something that causes Selenium to think "the reference to this is no longer valid" it will throw exceptions.

The fifth issue is you are looping through an array of `object`s which is unnecessary. You know their type. It's `IWebElement`. You are not harnessing the power of the class if you just define it as `Object`.

The final issue is that you are using `Thread.Sleep`. You are clearly waiting *for something* so use the explicit wait within Selenium to actually wait for *something* instead of "lets wait a few seconds".

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs

(remember Selenium is open source)

```
SelectElement actualSizeSelect = new SelectElement(UtilityClass.driver.FindElement(By.Id("SizeSelect")));
```

This then gives you the ability to search by text:

```
actualSizeSelect.SelectByText("10");
```

Now your test won't care where exactly in that list "10" is!

This would also give you the ability to loop through all the options within a given `select` like so:

```
IList<IWebElement> options = actualSizeSelect.AllOptions;
```

You now have a list of `option`s within that `select`. So let's loop through them:

```
foreach (IWebElement option in options) 
{
    option.Click(); // just a demo to show you.
}
```

Comment: Arran that's fantastic - thank-you for such a detailed response and I can confirm that it works perfectly.  However, I'm struggling to understand how I can verify that when I click on a drop down option, the width and height values in the style attribute get updated?  - <div id="Container" class="page" style="width: 547px; height: 865px; data-loaded="true">

Comment: Turns out that asserting the values of the width and height isn't going to work for me anyway as the size is relative to the screen size.  I can assert the values for my machine but if the display size changes or I'm running the tests on another machine then they will fail - much to my annoyance :)

Comment: Do they change by a certain value each time? I ask because I'm wondering if, for your case, you can just take a copy of what the values are *before* you do the click and compare it to what it is *after*. As long as the values are *greater than* what they were before, you have *some* test coverage there. You are testing *something*, this way.

Comment: Hi Arran.  Smart thinking :)  They do change and unfortunately (depending on screen resolution etc) the values will change (either more or less than the expected values) so I don't have something to compare with the previous or next values.  I played around with the SelectElement Class you showed me.  I can perform an assert.IsTrue(option.Selected); statement and it seems to work just fine even though there is no selected attribute applied to the options (confused).  I verified IsFalse throws an exception though.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction